# Injuries from armlocks with bent elbow

Tags: injury, joint-lock

I am interested in effects of armlocks with bent elbows. Depending on the typical two classes (external or internal rotation of the arm), I would like to know the following:

1. What exactly happens in the arm/shoulder, when an armlock is applied to the bent arm?
2. What are typical injuries?
3. Under which circumstances are shoulder or elbow injured?
4. Is there a difference between parts of the body that hurt and parts that get injured?

Comment: That is an extremely broad category of techniques with several difficult questions attached.  I would recommend breaking this down into several smaller questions.  

There are at least 5 different distinct 'bent arm' arm locks.  I'm not sure all of these are of interest though as 3 attack the wrist as well as the arm.  

Perhaps look at the aikido classifications of techniques?  These are relatively straight forward compared with Qi-na or Shorinji Kempo methods of classification.

Comment: It's basically: muscle/tendon pain due to stretching and twisting, torn muscles/tendons, sprains, dislocated joints, joint cartilage compression and tears, bone breaks / fractures, bruising.

Comment: I am particulary interested in the question when the shoulder and when the elbow is attacked/injured, as in judo, armlocks are only allowed on the elbow, and there is always discussion when an armlock attacks the shoulder and when it attacks the elbow.

Comment: does this help?  https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9352/why-is-ude-garami-legal-if-it-is-effectively-a-shoulder-lock?rq=1

Comment: or this perhaps? https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9082/is-there-a-way-to-reliably-attack-only-a-bent-elbow-joint-with-ude-garami-kimur?rq=1

Comment: This does not answer my question to 100%, but definitely helps and is very interesting. Thanks!

Comment: Are these the correct techniques as a place to start?

Comment: Yes, these are the techniques I am interested in.